# ImageIO.read illegal argument exception - raster bands/colour space components?

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio

Apologies for the somewhat vague title, I can't work out what the keywords are here. The setup's quite simple, I'm opening an image with

```
ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
```

This works for most files, however for one I get an `IllegalArgumentException with the detail: "numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match"`. This image was obtained via wget on a valid Flickr URL, and I've used other images obtained this way, so the method for obtaining images seems sound in principle. I'm not sure what's causing the exception.

A workaround would be more than acceptable - I'm not fussed with using `ImageIO` in particular, and the image looks fine visually. I just need to get it being read without Java freaking out!

Here's the image in question, in case it's of any use:

[image]

Comment: I get the same error (at least when using `ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i.imgur.com/rC6Jk.jpg"));`). Is this the only B/W image you are processing?

Comment: Hard to say - the nature of the image retrieval process is very undirected (the idea is that the software is autonomous!) It's the only one with such low saturation though. Do you think that's the cause?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Nope. I've had to rely on the fact that other images will be found if this error is raised.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I was having this same issue and found that the image was gray-scale and that the default ImageIO.read implementation was not figuring that out because the image metadata wasn't quite as expected.  I wrote a work around that retries the load as 'BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY' if it fails the main load.

```
            Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

        Exception lastException = null;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader reader = null;
            try {
                reader = (ImageReader)iter.next();
                ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
                reader.setInput(stream, true, true);
                Iterator<ImageTypeSpecifier> imageTypes = reader.getImageTypes(0);
                while (imageTypes.hasNext()) {
                    ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier = imageTypes.next();
                    int bufferedImageType = imageTypeSpecifier.getBufferedImageType();
                    if (bufferedImageType == BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY) {
                        param.setDestinationType(imageTypeSpecifier);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                bufferedImage = reader.read(0, param);
                if (null != bufferedImage) break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                lastException = e;
            } finally {
                if (null != reader) reader.dispose();               
            }
        }
        // If you don't have an image at the end of all readers
        if (null == bufferedImage) {
            if (null != lastException) {
                throw lastException;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The beauty of SO:  A problem that would have taken me two hours to figure out now takes 10 minutes.  Thank you, Tate Moore.

Comment: Wonderful stuff! Never thought anyone would come back and knock this one down but you did! Lovely stuff.

Comment: when I use this solution after it fails with ImageIO.read(InputStream) it does not execute the rest of the code (while (iter.hasNext()) is false), but if I omit ImageIO.read(InputStream) part it does the job.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: +1 because it works on some gray-scale cases, not working with ImageIO.read(...). But note, this code forces image load as gray-scale, even if it's not.  Yout have to make first a ImageIO.read(...) & if it fails, use this method.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering how to get that `stream`, if can be created by using `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(InputStream)` (this argument can be `FileInputStream`, `ByteArrayInputStream` etc).

Answer (score 4):

The error message is informative and indicates that the number of raster bands, as mentioned in the ICC color profile, seems to be incorrect. I used [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to strip the ICC profile from the  image. ImageIO subsequently has no problems reading the images (~1k bad images). Hope that helps.

Comment: It did! Thanks. I definitely think the message is informative, it's just above my level of understanding, not their fault. Thanks for commenting :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to read this image using TwelveMonkeys ImageIO, which is a more robust and forgiving replacement for the original ImageIO provided by the JRE.

See https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/

I found this solution in the PDF Box Jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3637

In order to use TwelveMonkeys, it is sufficient to add it as a maven dependency. It then registers itself before the default image processor.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twelvemonkeys.imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>imageio-jpeg</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```