# How to solve this "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match"?

Tags: java, image, raster, color-space

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

All I am trying to do is upload the image and save this as a blob.

Stacktrace:

```
17:11:07,613 ERROR [[Upload]] Servlet.service() for servlet Upload threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match
    at java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp.filter(ColorConvertOp.java:460)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.acceptPixels(JPEGImageReader.java:1235)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImage(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1203)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1014)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)

ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.compLogo);
            BufferedImage bii = ImageIO.read(byteStream);
```

Comment: Please show code, else it didn't happen.

Comment: what code do you want to see? im just doing the basic image upload.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageIO.read illegal argument exception - raster bands/colour space components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416378/imageio-read-illegal-argument-exception-raster-bands-colour-space-components)

Comment: The code causing the error of course.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is your friend.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11571181/1218322