# Scala ImageIO.read(byteArrayInputStream) IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match

Tags: javax.imageio

I am using ImageIo to directly read `ByteArrayInputStream` but for some specific images, I am getting the error as shown below:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match
```

I am not sure what exactly is going wrong here.

[image: Image Causing the issue]

I followed a bunch of threads in SO already:

[Getting a BufferedImage as a resource so it will work in JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007448/getting-a-bufferedimage-as-a-resource-so-it-will-work-in-jar-file)

[Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match when i read image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181306/numbers-of-source-raster-bands-and-source-color-space-components-do-not-match-wh)

[IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match For a color image Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351583/illegalargumentexception-numbers-of-source-raster-bands-and-source-color-space)

But not able to follow up on what exactly needs to be changed in the code to handle inappropriate images (which get some corrupted pixels while transformation).

Edit 1: I somehow displaced the confidential content and here's the image I am trying to read: https://i.imgur.com/r8vXYnB.jpeg

Can someone help me with the code to fix these image errors?

Comment: As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18400559/1428606) the problem is (most likely, as you don't share the file or the stack trace) that your image file contains an ICC profile that is not compatible with the image data. Using a different ImageIO plugin will probably fix it. What (if anything) you need to chagnge in your code is non-trivial, but impossible to say anyway as you don't share your code or image.

Comment: I am interested in understanding if I use JPEGImageReader Plugin instead of `javax.imageio.ImageIO` would that add extra level of safety reading those images? And what's the default reader that I can use to perform the same?

Comment: @HaraldK can you please confirm if I want to support this for BMP images I would need to add one more dependency like this: `"com.twelvemonkeys.imageio" % "imageio-bmp" % "3.9.3"` or adding only `"com.twelvemonkeys.imageio" % "imageio-jpeg" % "3.9.3"` would extend it for all other image supports that is needed?

Comment: Also Can I have list of supported formats by `javax imageio` default module? I see http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/ListAllreaderandwriterformatssupportedbyImageIO.htm that JPEG is supported however to use it I had to add the plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IllegalArgumentException: Numbers of source Raster bands and source color space components do not match For a color image Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351583/illegalargumentexception-numbers-of-source-raster-bands-and-source-color-space)

Comment: The formats supported by the JDK is listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/package-summary.html). JPEG format is supported. The problem is that your file contains an incompatible ICC profile, as explained in the linked/duplicate question, and the plugin handles this better (I verified the file, it's *exactly* the same problem). Same for BMP. It's supported by the JDK, but some types of BMP needs an extra plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was that by default JPEG is not supported for `javax.ImageIO`. I added this in my build to make things work:

```
      // JPEG Support
      "com.twelvemonkeys.imageio" % "imageio-jpeg" % "3.9.3"
```

Based on the image type you may have you would need to add more such extensions.

You can find all of them in this README: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/README.md